# Skipping whitespace excluding newlines in attoparsec

Tags: haskell, attoparsec

[Attoparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec) provides the function [`skipSpace`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.11.2.1/docs/Data-Attoparsec-ByteString-Char8.html#v%3askipSpace).

This function consumes all whitespace available.

How can I implement a function `skipSpaceNoNewline` that skips any whitespace except `\n` and `\r\n`?

*Note:* This question intentionally shows no research effort as it was answered Q&A-Style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine [`skipWhile`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.11.2.1/docs/Data-Attoparsec-ByteString.html#v%3askipWhile) and [`isEndOfLine`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.11.2.1/docs/Data-Attoparsec-ByteString-Char8.html#v%3aisEndOfLine) (which matches both `\n` and `\r\n`).

Using a lambda function, you can combine them to a `skipWhile` predicate that skips any whitespace except newlines.

```
skipSpaceNoNewline = skipWhile (\x -> isSpace_w8 x && not (isEndOfLine x))
```

Answer (score -2):

why not just use `skipSpaceNtoNewLine = filter (not.isSpace)`?

Edit: I was wrong. isSpace is useless. I thought `isSpace '\n'` is `False` but its `True`. Just check for space directly:

```
[ghci] putStrLn $ filter (/=' ') $ ";df g; lkdfg\n l sd;lfk sdf"
;dfg;lkdfg
lsd;lfksdf
```

Or to make sure you filter the right things:

```
[ghci] putStrLn $ filter (\m-> m `notElem` "\t\f\v") $ ";df g; lk\vdfg\n l sd;lfk sdf"
;df g; lkdfg
 l sd;lfk sdf
```

So your function becomes:

```
skipSpaceNtoNewLine = filter  (\m-> m `notElem` "\t\f\v")
```

Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: I think you misinterpreted the question. It's not about skipping spaces in a string, but in attoparsec. You provide a solution of signature `String -> String`, but what is required is a `Parser ()`

Comment: Besides that, I think your algorithm is slow (elem on list, you should usually use a set or a handwritten check), but most importantly it might be incorrect because to my knowledge the class of space characters contains more than `"\t\f\v"`, especially for unicode.